# Programmatically added trigger fails to pass the right argument

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I was trying to build a system of two separate Google forms feeding their answers to the same spreadsheet and run a different script/function depending on which form submitted the answers.

I came across this post:
[Trigger different Google Script functions after different form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970792/trigger-different-google-script-functions-after-different-form-submissions/46738695#46738695)

I used Jack's Brown suggestion to configure my projects triggers; I set two triggers, one for each form. Whenever I fill up either form the proper function/script is run, but it throws an error:

> Cannot read property "1" from undefined.

I quickly discovered why by adding as the first line of each function the following: `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` which produced this:

`Logger.log([{"response":{},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":1005336882076172400}, []]) [0 seconds]`

I realize that I'm passing an ActiveForm object with the questions and answers and I'm trying to read just the answer by using `e.values[i]`.

So the question is, how can I still use the `e` argument in my function and get the answers to the form? Can I use `e.response.getItemResponses();` and then the getResponse method for each item?

Comment: It's very good to share your search/research efforts but questions should be self contained, so please add [mcve] of your scripts. Reference [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The Forms [Form Submit Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) is different than the [Google Sheets Form submit Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).

Comment: @ Cooper - Thanks for your reply. I realized that much and succeeded with the following code:

Comment: Sorry, could not complete the comment in time. I was trying to post the code that worked but it complains is too long.